# How to listen to messages from a specific channel in every guild

Tags: python, discord.py

I want my bot to listen to every channel which is named "disminer-2" i am currently using

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os 
import asyncio
#from keepalive import keep_alive
from replit import db

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ">")
client.remove_command("help")

filtered = ["fuck","shit"]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))
  print("User: user Id : Message Content")

@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
  
  chn_id = msg.channel.id
  
  #all the filter things
  
  if msg.channel.name != "disminer-1" or msg.author.id == 844182812977659904 or msg.author.bot == True:
    return
  if msg.content.lower() in filtered:
    await msg.reply("Your message contains a filtered word.")
    return
  if msg.content.lower() in "https://" or msg.content.lower() in "https://":
    await msg.reply("Links cannot be sent through, so don't try to advertize, idiot. And now your punishment is get pinged 10 times, loser!")
    for i in range (0,10):
      await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
      await msg.channel.send(f"{msg.author.mention}")
    return
  if  "discord.gg" in msg.content.lower() or "discord.com" in msg.content.lower():
    await msg.reply("Links cannot be sent through, so don't try to advert your discord server, idiot. And now your punishment is get pinged 10 times, loser!")
    for i in range (0,10):
      await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
      await msg.channel.send(f"{msg.author.mention}")
    return
  
  channel = discord.utils.get([x for x in client.get_all_channels() if x.type is discord.TextChannel], name="disminer-2")

  await channel.send(f"**{msg.author}:** {msg.content}")
  print(f"{msg.author} : ({msg.author.id}) : {msg.content}")
  await client.process_commands(msg)

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
  for guild in client.guilds:
    for channel in guild.channels:
        await ctx.send (channel)


"""
Notes:
we might be able to do the for guild in thing
it seems to get all the channels.
"""

#keep_alive()
client.run(os.environ['BOTTOKEN'])
```

and am getting error

> Ignoring exception in on_message
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py",
> line 343, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> File "main.py", line 45, in on_message
> await channel.send(f"**{msg.author}:** {msg.content}")
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

any help appreciated thx.

Im basically trying to make a global bot which reads messages in disminer-1 and sends it to every guild it is in with the channel disminer-2.

Comment: `if msg.content.lower() in "https://" or msg.content.lower() in "https://":`??? these are equivalent conditions, why are you invoking both of them? Also, it should be the other way round: `if 'https://' in msg.content.lower():`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code.
First of all, you've got the check for the channel-type wrong.

Its

```
discord.ChannelType.text
```

not

```
discord.TextChannel
```

as found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.ChannelType).

Next, your implementation wont send to every channel. You will need to change the execution of your code.

```
for channel in client.get_all_channels():
    if (channel.type == discord.ChannelType.text) and (channel.name == "disminer-2"):
        await channel.send(f"**{msg.author}:** {msg.content}")
```